# Can I keep or install more than one Hypervisor Type-2 in a personal computer or laptop?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

Well-known Type-2 hypervisors are

- VMware Workstation,
- Microsoft Virtual PC,
- Oracle Virtual Box and
- Windows Hypervisor.

Can I keep or install all these hypervisors in a personal computer/ laptop?

Regards

TekQ

Answer (score 0):

In macos I have simultaneously run vmware and xhyve; and vbox and xhyve.  I've never run vmware + vbox;   It isn't smart, since both vbox + vmware are intrusive to the system state.   xhyve is well behaved, and you can happily run many of them without worry.